# Наложить изображение с альфа каналами друг на друга

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, opencv, .net-core

Есть два изображение с альфа каналами. На одном изображении(`fron`) изображен предмет с некоторой прозрачностью в альфа канала (от 0 до 255). Второе изображение просто фон.

Оба изображения одинакового размера. Ниже приведен код который отлично работает на Windows, но на Linux выдает белые следы где альфа канал изображения(`front`) меньше 255.

Хотел реализовать на OpenCV. Но ни чего не выходит. Как можно исправить?

```
var baseImage = new Bitmap( BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(back));
var overlayImage = new Bitmap(BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(front));

var finalImage = new Bitmap(baseImage.Width, baseImage.Height);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage);
graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

graphics.DrawImage(baseImage, 0, 0);
graphics.DrawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Узнать бы, откуда у вас `System.Drawing` в Linux взялось? Вы явно что-то стороннее используете.

Comment: Думаю проще будет использовать мультиплатформенную библиотеку вроде ImageMagic или как--то так. Уверен она это может и может и на виндовсе и на линуксе.

Comment: @Andrew, на ImageMagic не устраивала скорость работы. Но придется его использовать